# Scrapy spider shows errors of another unrelated spider in the same project

Tags: python, scrapy

Im trying to create a new spider by running `scrapy genspider -t crawl newspider "example.com"`. This is run in my recently created spider project directory C:\Users\donik\bo_gui\gui_project. As a result I get an error message:

```
  File "C:\Users\donik\bo_gui\gui_project\gui_project\spiders\requisites.py", line 6, in <module>
    from gui_project.gui_project.updated_kw import translated_kw_dicts
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gui_project.gui_project'
```

This error message refers to a different spider that I previously created in requisites.py that is called

```
class RequisitesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'requisites'
```

I cant understand why `genspider` command is even bothered with this old spider in requisites.py and thus denies creating a new spider. The requisites.py has these import statements that do not show any error when I run the spider to which the error is refering to, yet when I want to create a new spider suddenly the gui_project.gui_project module cannot be found:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from langdetect import detect
import re
from gui_project.gui_project.updated_kw import translated_kw_dicts
from urllib.parse import urlparse
```

If I comment out the `from gui_project.gui_project.updated_kw import translated_kw_dicts` and run `scrapy genspider -t crawl newspider "example.com"` again then my new spider is created succesfully. The same applies when I try to run a third spider in the same project. It also gets stopped due to an error in the requisites.py spider although they are not interconnected in any way and the names are different for each spider. cfg and settings files have not been moved.

Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try creating a new spider, `scrapy genspider` will check if a spider with that name already exists.
To do this, an instance of [`SpiderLoader`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#module-scrapy.spiderloader) is used.

`SpiderLoader` imports and caches all of the spiders in a project when initiated.
Since one of those imports results in an error, the command fails.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Only thing left unanswered is why would an error of the existing spider appear when running genspider if when I run the existing spider itself there are no errors. The module to which the error message refers is loading fine when the existing spider is launched

Comment: That probably has to do with how the code is executed, maybe another python version is used, or maybe `sys.path` is different...

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this situation， First of all, I use pycahrm and as we know, the pycharm project has two layers, like the image below.

[click here to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR19h.png)
For convenience we generally set up the inner layer of the project as Source Root, Pycharm can recognize it, but command line can't recognize it, so we need to do this, dynamically modifying the system path to let the command line know that we have the project of the layer inside as the home directory

```
sys.path.insert(0, "D:\Code\Python\ArticleSpider\ArticleSpider")
```